# Compile libusb library on Windows

Tags: compilation, window, libusb

I am writing C++ application which will be using libusb library. This application will be working on both linux and windows systems. Currently I am preparing application for windows system. I downloaded compiled libusb library, and I am linking it to my application. I am also using mingw compilers. Unfortunately while linker creates exe file it complains about missing `__ms_vsnprintf` functions. I think the libusb library I am linking was compiled in environment which was using missing functions. So I think building new libusb library on windows will solve that problem. In libusb repository (git://git.libusb.org/libusb.git) I found in file INSTALL_WIN, that I can build libusb using Visual Studio or Windows DDK/WDK. Unfortunately I can't install it. I also noticed, in root libusb directory there are some build linux scripts. Is there some other way to build libusb library without Visual Studio but only with mingw compilers?
Note: I am using Windows 7 64 bit

Answer (score 2):

libusb ships with a Visual Studio project you can use to build libusb on Windows. They are located in the `msvc` folder, an example is [libusb_dll_2017.vcxproj](https://github.com/libusb/libusb/blob/master/msvc/libusb_dll_2017.vcxproj).

Easier still, libusb has also been integrated in [vcpkg](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg), so you can just run `vcpkg install libusb` to get started.

Comment: Currently, I fixed that error. This is because I was using invalid library .a file. I don't remember how I got that file. But when I downloaded binaries from lubusb.info and used compiled library from MinGW32/ dir, it fixed the problem. For anyone please note target platform of library x86 vs. x64. I have 64-bit system, but when I was trying to compile 64-bit binary (using also 64-bit min-gw) I had errors. But when using 32-bit library, it was working fine. Next information for anyone dealing with libusb, use Zadig application to reinstall driver for libusb.